# User levels with PHP

Tags: php, authentication

What I'm trying to do is make it so that when a specific user level is set in my Database it shows up specific text. Here is my code.

```
$userget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `usertable` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$user = mysql_fetch_array($userget);

function getUserlevel() {
    if($user['userlevel'] == '1') { echo "Regular User"; }
elseif($user['userlevel'] == '2') { echo "Moderator"; }
elseif($user['userlevel'] == '3') { echo "Administrator"; }
else { echo "Undefined"; }
}
```

I know the function is working, because the Echo of Undefined works, which I set up as a test but the others are not working despite my user level being set to 3 and only echoing Undefined. A session is also set for when the user is logged in.

This is when the function is called.

```
<div class="userData">Welcome Back, <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?><hr /><?php 
getUserlevel(); ?></div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: There must be more code.... what are you passing to getUserlevel?

Comment: There is no more code to that.

    function getUserlevel() {

Is the function, as well as the name of the function.

Comment: This works as intended however.<?php } ?>
        <?php if($user['userlevel'] == 3) {?>
            <li id='last'><a href="admin/">ADMIN</a></li>
        <?php } ?>

Comment: Yes, but you still need to pass that variable to the function. Read zerkms link, and try my suggestion below. You need to either use a global keyword in your function (don't do that), or pass the variable explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to take a stab at:

```
getUserlevel($user['userlevel']);

function getUserlevel($usrlvl) {
    if($usrlvl == '1') { echo "Regular User"; }
elseif($usrlvl == '2') { echo "Moderator"; }
elseif($usrlvl == '3') { echo "Administrator"; }
else { echo "Undefined"; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just included query into function, and its working :P

```
<?php 

function getUserlevel() {

$userget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$user = mysql_fetch_array($userget);

    if($user['user_level'] == 1) { echo "Regular User"; }
elseif($user['user_level'] == 2) { echo "Moderator"; }
elseif($user['user_level'] == 3) { echo "Administrator"; }
else { echo "Error"; }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not access $user as $user[userlevel] because mysql_fetch_array return an array. Does username is unique if not use an id instead of using username. So you should write the function as below

```
 function getUserlevel()
 {
         foreach($user as $u)
         {
            if($u['userlevel'] == 1){echo "Regular User";}
            else if($u['userlevel'] == 2){echo "Moderator";}
            else if($u['userlevel'] == 3){echo "Administrator";}
            else{echo "Undefined";}
         }
  }
```

If it does not work make sure you have write a vaild mysql query